# finding a web framework

Tags: playframework, wicket, vaadin

I'm starting a new project that involves a web site that hosts a web application and would appreciate some help in deciding which web framework to choose.
Since I'm an eclipse developer in the last couple of years I would rather use a Java web framework (I Also find java to be much more maintainable and easier to test, debug and extend, but that is another topic .. )

I've done some research and the number of frameworks is staggering, you can't possibly go through them all in a reasonable time, that's why I'm addressing this wonderful community :-) 
Anyway, I've looked into GWT, Play!, Wicket, Vaadin and few others. In each of them there is something that I find problematic.

Vaadin and wicket for example both have a very nice widget set and is quite easy to use. I think that Programming web application with it is much easier than coding and debugging javascript code. Shortcomings are - all of the logic resides on the server and I find that it damages the user experience  (I've looked into some web sites that used Vaadin, and it felt like i'm logged in to a remote computer.. which is actually not far from the truth.. )

Play is great, but it lacks the GUI programming abilities of GWT and Vaadin, building a complex web application with pure jquery can be tedious, especially if there is AJAX involved.

Currently , I find play with the GWT plugin a reasonable solution. Is there anyone who is familiar with a better candidate?

Thanks!

Comment: A word of warning about Wicket though: although creating complex web applications for a couple of hundred concurrent users is very easy with it, you still have to put in a lot of effort to make it scale up. Make sure you understand the difference between stateful and stateless pages before you make your decision.

Comment: So from your experience, wicket and other stateful web frameworks are more difficult to scale? that makes sense ..

Comment: If you're doing a very high volume website, yes, stateful frameworks will affect its scaling negatively. Fortunately, it's not that hard to make stateless pages with Wicket (which don't hold any state on the server, thus helps a lot with the scaling). But you sure have to pay more attention, as you'll have to do with any other framework. If you use Play! (or any other stateless framework) and manually put lots of stuff in the HttpSession, it's even more risky than using a stateful framework that tightly controls its memory usage.

Comment: @Protostome Yes. Because wicket does almost everything on the server side, it's very hard to avoid having to create a session for each visitor, even a simple Ajax control can trigger session creation, and session sizes aren't small.

Comment: @tetsuo When I say very hard, I mean compared to how deceptively easy it is to create an application that works for low traffic volume.

Comment: @Protostome What we call stateful are applications that hold user state in server memory. Since a server has limited memory, and replicating it between servers is costly, it may be a limiting factor in your scaling (although there are meanings to mitigate this). That said, we almost always overestimate our scaling needs, and making the code more maintainable and modular is often more cost-effective than hand-coding the app with low-level stuff for maximum performance.

Comment: @tetsuo - I do not get what is stateless application. Those that hide the state in the page text? And also my impression was that in Servlets world session is always created by container. Having no key on the server side at all also looks insecure. Please explain.

Comment: @Dima Yes. In hidden fields, generated URLs' query parameters or javascript variables. The session is not created until you need (at least by Wicket, and the Servlet/JSP spec, other frameworks may always create it). It's possible to hold server-side authentication info outside the session, although this is the common practice, and not a specially bad one. As I said, people overestimate their scaling needs. Keep your session small, and defer its creation as long as you can (no session for unauthenticated, read-only users for example). You'll scale just fine, unless you're Facebook.

Comment: @Dima I'm only talking about scaling the presentation layer, of course. Optimizing it may create issues in other layers (for example, moving state from the session to the database). Some people have pride of their 'share nothing' architecture, but often they just move the problem, so they can blame SQL and have the chance to add 'NoSQL' to their curriculum, being paid for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of question is not really what StackOverflow is about, so please delete it after you get a satisfactory answer.

That said,

GWT is a nice solution if you want to minimize the overall network traffic, or better said, have finer control on the network traffic you application generates (you'll basically have a client application that communicates with the server when it needs data). It has some really rich component libraries, but once you pick one, it's not really trivial to mix and match with others, so you end up limited to that. And, laying out components with Java code is not that fun.

I don't know much about Play!, but it is an action-based framework so, even if it makes it really really simple to do things, the things it does are the basic things, you simply can't abstract and modularize your code like you can with a component-based framework.

Frameworks like Vaadin and Seam abstract too much, and take away from you the control you sometimes need over network traffic and resource consumption (specially Seam).

Wicket is built around the component abstraction (which helps a lot when building complex applications), but doesn't hide too much from you, letting you fine-tune it to your needs. The downside is, opposed to what you said, it doesn't have a very rich component library (although all the building blocks are there, and it's easy to integrate javascript libraries to add the 'richness').

Answer (score 2):

I think play, vaadin or gwt are different and it depends of your needs for your project.

Personally I'm using Play and I'm really happy with it. Once you're use to it, you gain a lot in productivity. Performances are also great !
I'm not familiar with Vaadin or GWT but from my point of view, jQuery is not that hard to learn and also with jQuery UI you have access to basic widgets very easily.
For me, you will have more useful skills if you learn play + jQuery, rather Vaadin or GWT.

In general way, I always prefer to choose the most popular framework or language, because you will have a lot of support from the community.

Comment: Yep, I guess you are right. I'm just a little concerned - a javascript code has the tendency to become very difficult to maintain once it reaches a certain size. But I guess a proper organization of code into modules could prevent such cases ...

Comment: 100% agree that javascript is hard. you should write it the less possible or buy a JavaScript expert or learn the Closure Tools Library (which is dedicated to big JavaScript development). There is no silver bullet. I think we should learn at less 1 action base framework (play), 1 component base framework (wicket) + 1 javascript framework (jquery, closure tool). vaadin and gwt is not so flexible but they are nice if we stay inside of its scope. good luck for your project